# Remove viewbox decimal and scale svg path to descired width & height

Tags: android, svg

I have a svg file that has decimal number viewbox value, I want to remove the decimal number since some software will have issue with it. Is there any way to scale it to an integer value?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="29dp"
    android:height="27dp"
    android:viewportWidth="6.9083"
    android:viewportHeight="6.3553">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#1276e7"
      android:pathData="M4.7153,0c-0.4826,0 -0.8099,0.1678 -1.2612,0.5483 -0.4512,-0.3806 -0.7785,-0.5483 -1.2612,-0.5483C0.8565,0 0,1.0658 0,2.5002 0,3.6134 1.0128,4.8393 3.0081,6.2167c0.2683,0.1848 0.6237,0.1848 0.892,0 1.9954,-1.3774 3.0082,-2.6033 3.0082,-3.7166 0,-1.4344 -0.8566,-2.5002 -2.193,-2.5002Z" />
</vector>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="_图层_2" data-name="图层 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6.90827050209009 6.355319979191336">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        isolation: isolate;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #1276e7;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="_形状_87_拷贝" data-name="形状 87 拷贝" class="cls-1">
    <g id="_形状_87_拷贝-2" data-name="形状 87 拷贝">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M4.71527733802759,0c-.48260498046875,0-.80987548828125,.1678466796875-1.26116943359375,.54827880859375-.451171875-.380615234375-.77850341796875-.54827880859375-1.26116943359375-.54827880859375C.85651268959009,0,.00000634193384,1.0657958984375,.00000634193384,2.50018310546875,.00000634193384,3.6134033203125,1.01276268959009,4.83929443359375,3.00812401771509,6.21673583984375c.268310546875,.18475341796875,.6236572265625,.18475341796875,.8919677734375,0,1.995361328125-1.37744140625,3.0081787109375-2.60333251953125,3.0081787109375-3.716552734375,0-1.43438720703125-.85662841796875-2.50018310546875-2.1929931640625-2.50018310546875Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see the width and height are integer but the `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` are decimal numbers, I want to scale the path to just match the `width` and `height` (29 x 27)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your `<path>` geometry you can try to **round all command coordinates to integers.**

You can use [yqnn's path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) for this task.

In your case rounding to integers alone will distort your path, since the heart command points will be aligned to a grid of 7x6 user units – we need a finer grid resolution.

[image: round to integers]

To fix this we can **scale the path** e.g. to 10 times it's original size and round all values once again to integers.

[image: scale]

I also recommend converting the commands to relative.
This way we can center the path in the new `viewBox` boundaries ('0 0 69 64') by adjusting the first M command  coordinates

```css
svg{
  width:29px;
  height:27px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="_图层_2" data-name="图层 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69 64">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        isolation: isolate;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #1276e7;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="_形状_87_拷贝" data-name="形状 87 拷贝" class="cls-1">
    <g id="_形状_87_拷贝-2" data-name="形状 87 拷贝">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M48 0c-5 0-8 2-13 5c-5-4-8-5-13-5c-13 0-22 11-22 25c0 11 10 23 30 37c3 2 6 2 9 0c20-14 30-26 30-37c0-14-9-25-22-25z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### Scale to 24x24

Responding to the OP's answer: You need a scaling factor of 3.474 (24 / 6.908299922943115*)
*Exact bounding box width – retrieved via `getBBox()`

As illustrated before: scaling and rounding will often result in undesired distortions caused by rounding errors.

You can try to manually adjust points in svg path editor.

```css
svg{
width:10em;
outline:1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M16.4 0c-1.7 0-2.8 0.6-4.4 1.9c-1.6-1.3-2.7-1.9-4.4-1.9c-4.6 0-7.6 3.7-7.6 8.7c0 3.9 3.5 8.1 10.5 12.9c0.9 0.6 2.2 0.6 3.1 0c6.9-4.8 10.5-9 10.5-12.9c0-5-3-8.7-7.6-8.7z" />
 </svg>
 
   <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
<path d=" m 33 0 c -3 0 -6 1 -9 4 c -3 -3 -5 -4 -9 -4 c -9 0 -15 7 -15 17 c 0 8 7 16 21 26 c 2 1 4 1 6 0 c 14 -10 21 -18 21 -26 c 0 -10 -6 -17 -15 -17 z" />
 </svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="m 16 0 c -2 0 -3 1 -4 2 c -2 -1 -3 -2 -4 -2 c -5 0 -8 4 -8 9 c 0 4 4 8 10 13 c 1 1 2 1 3 0 c 7 -5 10 -9 10 -13 c 0 -5 -3 -9 -8 -9 z" />
 </svg>
 
 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="m 16 0 c -3 0 -4 2 -4 2 c 0 0 -1 -2 -4 -2 c -5 0 -8 4 -8 9 c 0 5 4 8 10 13 c 1 1 3 1 4 0 c 6 -5 10 -8 10 -13 c 0 -5 -3 -9 -8 -9 z" />
 </svg>
 
 <p>1. scaled to 24x24;  1 decimal. <br>
 2. scaled to 48x48; integers <br>
 3. scaled to 24x24; integers – shows distortions <br>
 4. scaled to 24x24; integers – manually adjusted <br>
 </p>
```

As you can see in the snippet below, you can manually adjust the grid fitting to fix distortions. However, the visual result differs significantly from the original.

Usually, it's better to choose an appropriate coordinate grid resolution providing enough values to **match the path's level of details.**.
Less than 100x100 units will most likely result in distortions when rounding to integers.
FontAwesome icons for instance use a viewBox with ~ 512x512 to retain fine details.
Better round up to 1 decimal place and make sure that your graphic is not cropped due to the rounded ViewBox values.

#### Android vector drawables and floating point numbers

1 or 2 decimals are usually not a problem but I frequently encountered the problem of cropped viewports:
`android:viewportHeight="6.3553"` might be rounded down to 6 and crop the bottom of your graphic.
So **rounding up** the viewport values to integers can often fix rendering problems.

#### Batch scaling

You might adapt this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/VwBmKzQ) for your needs.
It will scale and center svgs to a new viewBox and also add some padding to avoid cropping.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! This works perfectly! I have another question, is their a  way to scale it to desired width and height. For instance, I want to scale it to 24 * 24

Comment: @Hhry That should't be necessary as long as your viewport and your width and height values share the same aspect ratio. I've addded some more explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! yqnn's github editor was a good tool to use for single edit. Is there any tool or script or library that can be used to batch process svg (scale & round)? I have like 130 of them all have decimal points and cropped because of viewports in android development too. It's annoying but the UI designer exported svg all have these floating point numbers

Comment: What's more, I have one interesting svg file who has a width of 30.029 and a height of 30. It is possible to get rid of the .029?

Comment: I've added a codepen link that might be helpful to normalize your icons. However, you should concider using a better crafted icon library. Quite likely your UI designer just assembled the svg from different sources. So I always recommend to thoroughly inspect all icons for distortions - no app can "automagically" fix these errors.